alexa.SmartVision.ObjectDetectionSensor Interface 1.0
does someone have a sample skill code with alexa.SmartVision.ObjectDetectionSensor Interface 1.0 implementation , because I have been trying from a long time to implement this for a doorbell device ,but the alexa app doesnts seem to show the person and package detection option in it,
I tried adding the alexa.SmartVision.ObjectDetectionSensor Interface 1.0  and the dataController interface in the discovery response for the doorbell device, am I missing any other interface , ?
